# Python : Looking for more efficient regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract each firm's consumer data from 10-k statement.

My specific target sentence is

(for example) "Consumer A, Consumer B accounted for ~~~ ~~~~~ of sales."

However there are a lot of variants with this sentence

There are some points to consider, to take all those variants into consideration

1.
for example, accounted can be accounts \ account \ accounting \ represents \ represented \ represent \ representing (In addition if represent appears, there should be no "for" in the target sentence)

and sales can be sale \ revenue \ revenues

2. Since, the company names sometimes appear 1 or 2 sentences before/after that target sentence. I would like to extract target sentence + 2 sentences before/after that at the same time. However, some of the company names contain ".", like "Toyota, Inc.," and "U.S. department of defense" . Thus, If I try to extract 2 sentences before this target sentence ("Toyota, Inc., accounted for ~~~ ~~~~~ of sales" ), based on the number of "." before the target sentence, this only extract one sentence before the target sentence.

So, considering this two points I made my regular expression,

```
[.][^.]*[.][^.]*[.][^.]*[A-Z\.|\.\,]*[^.]*(account|accounted|accounts|accounting|represents|representing|represent|represented)(\sfor)?.{0,100}(sale|revenue)[^.]*\.?[^.]*\.',
re.I|re.S
```

However, this regular expression works so slow...

Could you help me understand how to improve this regular expression?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe use CPython, Cython, JPython, or IronPython. I am not an expert at any of these but I believe that using Cython would dramatically increase your speed. Best of luck and cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure what the `re.I|re.S` bit means at the end of your regex. If you give some sample lines, then we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your regex is too general at the start, and then too specific at the end. The regex engine can match *almost anything* against the first few symbols of your regex, so it'll try thousands of combinations of a string before ever getting a match, due to the tougher end conditions.

**Note: You didn't give me any sample text, so I did my best.**

This expression is much simpler, but does the job "good enough". By allowing some limitations, the runtime will be improved by a lot.

```
(\s\S+){1,5}\s(account|represent)[\s\S]{5,100}?(sale|revenue)s?
```

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/3ZYwzz/3)

For example, as long as the word "account" or "represent" are there, it doesn't care what the suffix is. If someone types "representenedsing", then it'll pick that up, but we can assume such a thing won't happen.

Furthermore, this regex doesn't try to find sentences before or anything complex. It just takes up to 5 words before the word "account" or "represent", and uses them. Of course, you can easily change this value.

Explanation:

---

This gets 5 words containing ANY characters, separated by ANY space/newline.

```
(\s\S+){1,5}\s
```

---

The word "account" or represent".

```
(account|represent)
```

---

At least 5, but up to 100 of characters of any type. The `?` makes it "LAZY", so it'll stop as soon as it hits the next condition (the word "sale" or "revenue").

```
[\s\S]{5,100}?
```

---

The word "sale" or "revenue", with an optional "s" at the end.

```
(sale|revenue)s?
```